# Is there a way to create a counter that gradually decreses in increment size?

Tags: python, for-loop, tkinter

I need to create a counter which will give an effect of slowing down gradually on a spinning object.

I thought that the best way to do this is to create a counter that gradually decreses in increment size as time passes (Like an inversley proportional graph).

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
import time
for i in range(10):
   time1=time.time()
   time.sleep(0.2*i) #you can change this as you want, like for 1st iteration 0.2, then 0.4 sec...
   print("slowed by : ", time.time()-time1)
```